# How to enable user search in Apache Solr?

Tags: search

I have Apache Solr running on my site, but would like to get it to index users as well as nodes, so that a single search request will bring up matching users as well as nodes.  What do I need to do to make this possible?  I found some pages talking about installing the Content Profile module to create nodes corresponding to users, which solr could then presumably find, but Content Profile doesn't seem to have made the jump to Drupal 7.  Is something like this required, or will Solr just do this once I tweak some configuration step that I apparently missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the Apachesolr User module, which has just a development snapshot release for both Drupal 6, and Drupal 7. It is used from 76 sites, 72 of which run Drupal 7.

Basing on the module description, it could suit for you.

> This module will add users to apache solr. It is compatible with the latest beta of Apache Solr search integration.
>   It now exposes the User entity type as an indexable entity type so it can be indexed properly. All Apache Solr hooks are available to modify the way you are indexing users.

Looking at the issue queue for the module, I found [Only users with the "Bypass content access control" permission are able to search for users when Apache Solr Access is enabled](http://drupal.org/node/1665350). Before using the module I would rather wait that issue is fixed. If you aren't using the ApacheSolr Access module, you should not have the issue reported there. That is what a user commented.

Comment: Excellent!  Exactly what I was looking for.  There do seem to be some issues with the access module; I'll need that eventually, and will try to look in on it and see if I can help.